# Typeorm update multiple many-to-many relations

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am currently using `nestjs` and `typeorm` with `sqlite` for development purpose and `postgress` for production. I have the following entities:

Realm:

```
@Entity()
export class Realm {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', { name: 'id' })
  _id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  notes: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Client, (client) => client.realm, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  clients: Client[];

  @OneToMany(() => Role, (role) => role.realm, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  roles: Role[];

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.realm, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  users: User[];
}
```

Role:

```
@Entity()
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', { name: 'id' })
  _id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  @Generated('uuid')
  code: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  def: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => Realm, (realm) => realm.roles, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  realm: Realm;

  @ManyToMany(() => Client, (client) => client.roles, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  clients: Client[];

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.roles)
  users: User[];
}
```

User:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(`${User.name}Entity`);

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', { name: 'id' })
  _id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  verified: boolean;

  @ManyToMany(() => Role, (role) => role.code)
  @JoinTable()
  roles: Role[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Realm, (realm) => realm.users, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  realm?: Realm;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @AfterInsert()
  afterIntesr() {
    this.logger.log(`A new user was created: ${this} at ${this.createdAt}`);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the role has a flag called `def`. In my case I want to add the role to all users from a Realm, if the added role is marked as default(`def: treu`).

Right now, I am doing something like this:

```
  async updateDefaultRoles(realm: Realm, role: Role) {
    const users = await this.userRepo.find({ where: { realm: { _id: realm._id } }, relations: ['roles'] });
    users.forEach((user) => user.roles.push(role));
    this.userRepo.save(users);
  }
```

I am sure this is quite ineficient, but I was wondering if there is a way to use the `createQueryBuilder().relation(User, 'roles')` to update all of them? I see the [typeorm documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relational-query-builder) that shows how to do it on a single entity, but not on multiple ones.

I tried something like this:

```
    await this.userRepo
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .relation(User, 'roles')
      .of({ realm: { _id: realm._id } })
      .add(role);
```

But I am getting an error regarding the roleId in the relation table of being null.

Here is the error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: user_roles_role.userId`.

I would appreciate any help or direction in order to solve this. Thanks!

If there is no way on this route, maybe a plain sql query would help.